# Wrapping passport.authenticate inside a function doesn't work

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate user using Google OAuth2Strategy. I have below routes

```
**server.get('/user/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['openid email profile']});
server.get('/user/google/callback', authenticate.authenticateGoogleCallback);**
```

and this works completely fine. but when I wrap the first authenticate like how i have done for callback, it just hangs. It it a bug or i am doing something wrong?

This is what i am trying.

```
**server.get('/user/google', authenticate.authenticateGoogle); // NOT WORKING
server.get('/user/google', function(req,res,next){ // NOT WORKING
     passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['openid email profile']});
});**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this and let us know if its work. (you have to provide (res,req,next) in end of function as described in this link http://passportjs.org/docs)

```js
server.get('/user/google', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
     scope: ['openid email profile']
  } ,function(err, user, info){
    res.send(user);
  })(req,res,next);
})
```

Comment: For Koa (koajs.com) replace `(req, res, next)` by `(ctx, next)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I wrapped the passport.authenticate in one of my project:

```
server.get('/user/google', (req, res, next) => {
  // making additional checks [you can skip this]
  const auth = req.header('Authorization')

  if (auth) {
    // this is what you are looking for
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(req, res, next)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```