# Wrapping passport.authenticate *callback* inside a function doesn't work

Tags: passport.js, koa

This is closely related to [Wrapping passport.authenticate inside a function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327284/wrapping-passport-authenticate-inside-a-function-doesnt-work).

We are using [Koa](http://koajs.com) instead of [Express](http://expressjs.com). Hence I replaced the `(req, res, next)` by `(ctx, next)`. It worked fine for the initial oauth2 call, but the callback throws an error if wrapped in a function.

**Works:**

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google',
    {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/fail',
        failureFlash: true,
    }));
```

**Fails:**

```
const google_callback = (ctx, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('google',
        {
            successRedirect: '/auth/success',
            failureRedirect: '/auth/fail',
            failureFlash: true,
        }
    )(ctx, next);
};
router.get('/auth/google/callback', google_callback);
```

The error message is:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037287/can-not-set-header-in-koa-when-using-callback) pointed me in the right direction.

**Works:**

```
const google_callback = async (ctx, next) => {
    await passport.authenticate('google',
        {
            successRedirect: '/auth/success',
            failureRedirect: '/auth/fail',
            failureFlash: true,
        }
    )(ctx, next);
};
```